# What kind of encryption mechanisms does SQL Server 2008 Standard offer?

Tags: sql, sql-server, security, sql-server-2008, encryption

As I see, TDE and EKM mechanisms are available only in Enterprise edition. How can I encrypt data in tables in Standard edition of SQL Server 2008?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have native encryption capabilities available.

In this article (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179331.aspx) an example is provided showing how to do the following:

Master key 
Certificate 
Symmetric key 
Apply the encryption key to the column.

You do not need to have enterprise edition for this option.

The article above tells you step by step on implementing a column level encryption.