# Running SQL Server on an encrypted drive/partition

Tags: sql-server-2008, encryption, windows-7-x64

Has anyone had experience with this?  I am running Windows 7 x64 on my laptop with Visual Studio 2010 and SQL Server 2008.  I am pondering the idea of whether this is possible and what the effect would be on performance to encrypt the drive with PGP, OpenCrypt or some other utility.

I had thought of the following scenarios that I would use to do this:
1. Encrypt the drive straight out, it and all of it's contents.
2. Create a second un-encrypted partition and move the SQL data files to that partition and point SQL Server to that path.
3. Create a second un-encrypted partition and install SQL Server to that path along with its data files.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a paper from Microsoft about that topic. It only covers the Microsoft encryption techniques but Bitlocker is very similar like drive encryption software (PGP, TrueCrypt,...).

[Database Encryption in SQL Server 2008 Enterprise Edition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278098.aspx#_Toc189384687)

In the conclusion it says: "EFS and BitLocker are also valid solutions either in conjunction with TDE or as standalone encryption systems."

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server 2008 will not install on an encrypted drive (or compressed for that matter).  At the moment, all I can find is [this forum post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlgetstarted/thread/fa0b7fe0-6e98-4c9c-85e3-1a0f094e3f04/) on Microsoft Social about a similar issue.  The error message, however, is telling.  You can, instead, install SQL Server and create databases on an unencrypted partition and use SQL Server's built-in [encryption mechanisms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2873065/what-kind-of-encryption-mechanisms-does-sql-server-2008-standard-offer).

Answer (score 0):

It appears Microsoft has fixed this issue with SQL Server 2012.  I installed and have SQL Server 2012 running on my bitlocker encrypted Windows 8.1 tablet.